# Masking options with bitwise operators in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I want to know how can I mask a value so I can set up configurations. Let's supose I have **constants** `Options.A = 0`, `Options.B = 1` and so on...

```
builder.setOption( Option.A & Option.C ); // Or should I use '|' operator?
```

This would mean that

```
Option.A    Option.B    Option.C    Option.D
    1           0           1           0
```

Since `1010` is binary for number `10`, it would mean that `builder.option = 10;`, but in the actual implementation I'd have a `switch` case that would compare it like:

```
// inside builder.someFunction();
switch(this.option) {
    case Option.A & Option.C:
```

**Note:** please correct me if this is not how you use bitwise operators to mask values, I have read a lot and don't understand it well, so if this is wrong I'm probably gonna need an example like this with `switch-case`.

**PS:** I took for example a line of code from `Android` framework that goes like this:

```
view.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
```

That's a similar behavior I want to achieve.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Haven't tried it, I'm not totally sure of... what's next. I'm new to bitwise operators and their use, so I want to get a clear idea of what I am doing before actually coding it

Comment: You need to use or ('|') in both cases.

Comment: Have you considered using the BitMask API?

Comment: Why not try `&`ing a couple things together and check the result? Then try `|`ing a couple things together and see what that looks like. By the time you're done you may have learned something. The best skill you can develop as a software developer is how to figure things out for yourself. Otherwise every time you want to do something you haven't done before you're going to have to come here and ask somebody to figure out how to do it for you.

Comment: @MikeB that's usually what I do, the thing with bitwise is that I don't know what to try. I could do `8 & 10` or any other expression but I wouldn't understand without the basics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First, for theory:**

(1)We ignore **data types**, suppose you have 4 options:

```
Option.A    Option.B    Option.C    Option.D
```

Then you need to use a 4bit-width variable to represent them. Suppose Option.A is the highest(Left-most) bit and the Option.D is the lowest(Right-most). Then this variable looks:

```
Option.A    Option.B    Option.C    Option.D
  bit3        bit2        bit1        bit0
```

Its range is 0000~1111, represents 2^4 = 16 different combinations.

(2)For bit operations, you should firstly define the mask for each option:

```
var Mask.A = 1000;
var Mask.B = 0100;
var Mask.C = 0010;
var Mask.D = 0001;
```

<1>If you want to represent a value which has Option.B and Option.C, you can use `OR` operation:

```
var v_B_and_C = Mask.B | Mask.C = 0100 | 0010 = 0110;
```

<2>If you want to check whether a value contains Option.B, use `AND`, then compare the result:

```
var some_v = 1101;
var result = some_v & Mask.B = 1101 & 0100 = 0100;
if(result != 0000) {// Contains Option.B! }
else {// ==0000. Not contains Option.B! }
```

<3>If you want to reverse a value, you can use `NOT`/`XOR` :

```
var some_v = 0011;
var reversion_v = ~some_v = ~0011 = 1100;
// you can also use XOR(^) between a value and an all-1 constant
var reversion_v = some_v ^ 1111 = 0011 ^ 1111 = 1100;
```

<4>If you want to know the difference between two values, can use `XOR`:

```
var v_1 = 1100, v_2 = 0110;
var diff = v_1 ^ v_2 = 1100 ^ 0110 = 1010 // Means bit3, bit1 are different!
```

<5>For other usage, ref: [Bitwise Operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation)

**Second, for practice in Java:**

(1)The 1st thing you need to make clear is that how many `Options(bits)` you need to represent?
Because different data types has different width(represent different range):

- short: 2Bytes, 16bit, represents 2^16 = 65536 combinations.
- int: 4Bytes, 32bit, represents 2^32 = 4294967296 combinations.
- long: 8Bytes, 64bit, represents 2^64 = 18446744073709551616
  combinations.

If you need more than 64 Options, you may need to use array(int[]/long[]), or an convenient class: [java.util.BitSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

(2)If you want to implement yourself by array, use the bitwise operation keywords(&,|,^,~,<<<,>>>). There is a tips to print out an int in binary format:

```
int i = 0x80000000;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(i));
// Print: 10000000000000000000000000000000
```

(3)I recommend use the `java.util.BitSet` class, unless you have reasons that must implement yourself. Example:

```
import java.util.BitSet;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Create a BitSet object, which can store 128 Options.
      BitSet bs = new BitSet(128);
      bs.set(0);// equal to bs.set(0,true), set bit0 to 1.
      bs.set(64,true); // Set bit64

      // Returns the long array used in BitSet
      long[] longs = bs.toLongArray();

      System.out.println(longs.length);  // 2
      System.out.println(longs[0]); // 1
      System.out.println(longs[1]); // 1
      System.out.println(longs[0] ==longs[1]);  // true
   }
}
```

Other usage, [see the java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

Comment: Holy cow, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I have never implemented this but it occurs to me something like this:

For the first question, yes you would need to use | (instead of &) to accumulate the options correctly

if you are gonna accumulate options inside one variable, then to check which options are ON I would use a **for**:

```
for(int i=0;i<32;i++){
    if(i&options){//check if i-th option is ON
        option_function(i);
    }
}
```

and inside option_function() do the switch case.

```
void option_function(int i){
    switch(i) {
        case Option.A:
            ....
}
```

}

Comment: This gives me the heads up to start trying stuff on my own

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a class thats easier to read and uses standard API's?

```
public class Permissions { 

    final BitSet permissions;

    public Permissions() {
        permissions = new BitSet();
    }

    public void setPermission(int p) {
        permissions.set(p);
    }
}
```